# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException

Tags: java, spring, junit, noclassdeffounderror, spring-test

I've set up a Spring project, and I got an exception when running the following test.

```
package com.company.app;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring-config.xml"})
public class CheckTest {

    @Test
    public void test_foo() {
        assertEquals(0, 1);
    }
}
```

The exception is as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:281)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$2.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:207)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assume$AssumptionViolatedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 22 more
```

I found that `AssumptionViolatedException` was located in `org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException` instead of `org.junit.Assume`, I think maybe this is reason why the exception was thrown.

But if I remove the following annotation lines, it would work just fine

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring-config.xml"})
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :1
```

Most answers I got from the Internet told me that I should use junit and spring-test with a higher version. But I think I'm using the highest versions for both of them.

```
junit: 4.12
spring-test: 4.3.2.RELEASE
```

Is there any other things I should do to make it work? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: Judging by the error the junit version you think you are using isn't the actual version you are using. Check your dependencies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually **not** using `spring-test` 4.3.2.

Rather, you have a **very old** version of `spring-test` on your classpath.

`SpringMethodRoadie` was introduced in Spring 2.5 for JUnit 4.4 support, and if I recall correctly, `SpringMethodRoadie` was removed in Spring 3.0 with the upgrade to JUnit 4.5.

The solution is to configure your build or IDE to use the correct version of `spring-test`.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: I added two `spring-test` dependencies in `pom.xml` and it used the older one, it worked after I removed the older dependency, thank you.